# rails collection_select params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grouped-collection-select

So I am trying to filter some data based on a collection_select drop down box.

I can successfully use a text_field_tag to filter the data, so I assume my filter is working fine, but I can't get the collection_select to do the same?

If I type a 1 into the text_field_tag, I generate "search"=>"1" as a part of the parameters, but if I select from the collection_select I get... 
{"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"search"=>"1"},...

index.html.erb

```
 <h1>Students#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/students/index.html.erb</p>

<%= form_tag students_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= collection_select :search ,  :search.to_s, Tutor.all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  <%= submit_tag "search" %>
<% end %>

<% @students.each do |n| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to n.first_name, student_path(n) %>
    <%= n.surname %> ..tutor is...
    <%= n.tutor.name %>
  </li>
 <% end %>

<%= params.inspect %>

<%= form_tag(students_path, :method=> "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Students" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tutor

  def self.search(search)
    where("tutor_id LIKE ?","%#{search }%")
  end
end
```

students_controller.rb

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @students = Student.search(params[:search])
    else
      @students = Student.all
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how [**collection_select**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) work. The first parameter of `collection_select` is an ***object*** not a ***method***, so your params look like that.

Changing `params[:search]` to `params[:search][:search]` should solve your problem.

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search][:search]
      @students = Student.search(params[:search][:search])
    else
      @students = Student.all
    end
  end
end
```